# JQuery Load() only brings up 1 #fragment

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Okay here's a something that's had me scritching my head. Here's a scaled down version of my code.

This is to capture a click on an element and load portions of another html document based on the item clicked.

Here's the Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".sublist >li").click(function(){
        $("#box").html("").load("hompageEditor.html #"+$(this).attr("name"));
    });
});
```

And here is the HTML of the main document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Webster Memorial Administration - Notices</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../_scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="content">

<div id="default">
    <p >This section allows changes to the home page .. The Image Slider,&nbsp; the Welcome Box, the About Us, Connection, and Order of Service. 
    As you tytpe the Live Preview Pane will update allowing you to see an approximation of how the text will appear in the page.</p>
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="box"></div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The idea is that the information in the #box element will change.

Now here's a strip down of what the document that's supposed to load looks like:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head></head>
<body>
 <div id="welcome">
     <p>Some Text</p>
     <div class="editor">Some stuff</div>
     <div class="preview">Some stuff</div>
 </div>
 <div id="about">
     <p>Some Text</p>
     <div class="editor">Some stuff</div>
     <div class="preview">Some stuff</div>
 </div>
 <div id="oos">
     <p>Some Text</p>
     <div class="editor">Some stuff</div>
     <div class="preview">Some stuff</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

With me so far?

Now the this for some reason only works for the  #welcome element.  All the others don't work. when the fragment is called via load. To test something I tried changing up the order of the elements in various ways. Regardless of where it occurs The #welcome fragment is the only fragment that load(_) seems to pull. There are no errors showing up in the firefox console either.

WHile I have found a work around I'd really like to know why this doesn't work.

My apologies isf my formatting is crumby. FIrst post here.

UPdate Ah.. Okay I've been asked to show the sublist. This is the Navigational component. .sublist exists just to provide a selector target.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul class="mainlist">
    <li name="messages">Edit Messages
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li name="welcome">Welcome</li>
            <li name="about">About Us</li>
            <li name="oos">Order of Service</li>
            <li name="wwd">What We Do</li>
            <li name="connect">Connection</li>
        </ul></li>
    <li name="slideshow">Edit Slideshow
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li name="preview">Preview Slideshow</li>
            <li name="addel">Add/Delete Pictures</li>
            <li name="edit">Edit Settings</li>
        </ul></li>


</ul>
</div>
```

I should also point out that the file that all of this is in is called homeEdit.php

Comment: A list element [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) doesn't support a `name` attribute`. You may want to use a `data` attribute, like `data-name`

Comment: I know it doesn't normally but for this bit of pagery I have managed to get it to work as a shortcut. It actually works and that's not the part that's causing me consternation.

Comment: When you click each one you get the `name` attribute data? Can you setup a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem? Can you show us `.sublist`?

Comment: Okay UI updated it with the infor from the navigational elemnt and I'm trying tos ee if I can get jsfiddle to work with this.